# is my following fingering even a thing?

Tags: piano, fingering

[image]

My trouble is with the LH in the bass clef, I start with thumb on E4, then index on B3, then pinky on E3, spanning an octave, then switch to thumb on E3 so my pinky is ready to jump to A2 in the next measure.

The switch from pinky to thumb at E3, is it very bad practice? I'm very new to piano just trying to figure out fingerings.

Answer (score 2):

No its not bad practice. There's a lot of variations in fingering that you can do for this; just do whatever makes it  manageable and sound good.

If you have long fingers you can do `2 1 2 2 5` as well, but that might not work for faster tempi.

Answer (score 1):

I think either `LH: 1 2 5 4-1 5` or `1 2 5 1 5` would feel OK. `4-1` being a silent finger change.

Answer (score 1):

Since everything in the first bar is part of the same harmony, you may well be using pedal for the whole bar. In that case, when you need to bounce off the low E, it'll sound like you're still holding it down anyway, giving you time to let go and move to the low A.

That said, as in the other answers, whatever works for you. The only real rule on fingering is to find (by trial and error!) *your* best option. It may well be no-one else's but isn't that better than trying to play, with difficulty, what someone else says is the way to do it?